# Exeption Handling

Tags: java, exception

Why does the following code not execute,

```
try {
        System.out.println("abc");
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

but why does this execute

```
    try {
        System.out.println("abc");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: By not "execute", do you mean not "compile"? If so, then the compilation error says it all: *Unreachable catch block for `FileNotFoundException`. This **exception is never thrown from the try statement body***

Comment: What do you mean by exeute and not execute ?

Comment: You should read about `Checked` and `Unchecked` exceptions. Refer this https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Checked_Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

A print statement will not throw a `FileNotFoundException` error whereas `Exception` will catch any generic exception in Java.

Answer (score 0):

That is because FileNotFoundException is a so-called Checked Exception.
It can only occur if System.out.println explicitly throws it.
The Compiler can detect that & will flag it.

On the other hand, Exception could be masking a RuntimeException or Subclass thereof.
(for example NullPointerException, which need not be explicitly declared)
The Compiler cannot detect that, and therefore must allow subclasses of RuntimeException, RuntimeException itself, Exception and Throwable.